# SQL LIMIT return 'zero' - 0 - rows(IN PHP)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, limit

I have an error in this query, when the query returns zero rows.


**Error Number: 1064**

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-20,20' at line 3

SELECT pl.name,pl.email FROM players pl JOIN players_bonus pl_b on pl.id = pl_b.id_player WHERE pl_b.id_bonus = 3 LIMIT -20,20


My method is:

```
    public function getPViews_num_rows($limit = array(0,20),$page_num = 1,$id) {
        $limit = "LIMIT {$limit[0]},{$limit[1]}";
```

```
    $sql = "SELECT pl.name,pl.email FROM players pl 
            JOIN players_bonus pl_b on pl.id = pl_b.id_player 
                WHERE pl_b.id_bonus = ? {$limit}";

    $where =  array($id);
    $query = $this->db->query ( $sql,$where );
    return $query->num_rows ();
}
```

I don't wanna do another query to count rows,before I do this query.
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not specify ***negative*** value to `LIMIT` clause:

```
LIMIT -20,20
```

It means you want to return `20` rows starting from `-20` which is ***wrong***.

Comment: Limit by default is 0,20 its not negative..!!
$limit = array(0,20)

Comment: @Oyeme: I know but you are specifying negative `-20, 20` in your query `SELECT pl.name,pl.email FROM players pl JOIN players_bonus pl_b on pl.id = pl_b.id_player WHERE pl_b.id_bonus = 3 LIMIT -20,20`. You will have to modify your function to not allow negative values for the `limit` clause.

Comment: thanks you.. i found my error..i used codeigniter core,its codeigniter bug i used like this $this->db->limit(0, 30);  AND it works..

Answer (score 4):

The `OFFSET` value of the `LIMIT` clause has to be a nonnegative integer constant. Quoting the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which **must both be nonnegative integer constants** (except when using prepared statements).

Answer (score 2):

The limit cannot be negative.