# INSERT INTO SELECT,copy value+ 'string'

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to copy a row .
Copied row,I need to change value, this value + 'copy'
I made this sql..but it's not work..

```
INSERT INTO prizes_i18n (
  lang_id
  , translation_name
  , translation_desc
  , name
  , lang_path)
SELECT  prizes_s.lang_id
        , prizes_s.translation_name +  'copy'
        , prizes_s.translation_desc
        , prizes_s.name
        , prizes_s.lang_path   
FROM    prizes_i18n prizes_s 
WHERE   prizes_s.lang_id = 637;
```

Without + 'copy' its works.
Like this `prizes_s.translation_name +  'copyy'`,but it's not work.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean? Does it give an error? Does it fail silently?

Comment: How does it fail? Are you getting an error or are you not getting the value you want in the result

Comment: incorrect double value.. only accepted 'copy' - like string or column name ,together to combine it - not works

Comment: Please expand on "it's not work".  Do you get an error?  If so, what is it?  Run time or compile time?  The more details you provide, the more likely it is you will get a right answer.

Comment: whats the datatype of translation_name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351323/sql-limit-return-zero-0-rowsin-php) you use MySQL? If so use `concat` for string concatenation.

```
SELECT 'foo' + 'bar' ...
```

Returns `0` in MySQL which would explain the error about doubles you are seeing.

```
INSERT INTO  prizes_i18n (lang_id, translation_name, translation_desc, 
                          name, lang_path)
SELECT  prizes_s.lang_id,
    concat(prizes_s.translation_name, 'copy'),    
    prizes_s.translation_desc, prizes_s.name, prizes_s.lang_path  
FROM prizes_i18n prizes_s WHERE prizes_s.lang_id = 637;
```

Comment: You got there just before I did.  I think most DBMS flavours have CONCAT()

Answer (score 1):

Random guess...

`prizes_s.translation_name + ' Copy'` is too long for translation_name and you get `string or binary data would be truncated` error?

Is it SQL Server too? Is translation_name `char` or `varchar`?

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO 
prizes_i18n
(lang_id,translation_name,translation_desc,name,lang_path)
SELECT
prizes_s.lang_id
, concat(prizes_s.translation_name,'copy')
, prizes_s.translation_desc
, prizes_s.name
, prizes_s.lang_path
FROM 
prizes_s WHERE prizes_s.lang_id = 637;

Also I think, that in your FROM clause the table prizes_i18n is unnecessary.

Comment: There is only one table there `prizes_i18n`. It is aliased as `prizes_s`